# Run specific application from a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure you all have seen those links are able to run for example Yahoo Messenger application on client side if it is installed on client machine. I want to know bit more about how should I register my protocol (I don't even know what should I call that) to open my specified application.

**Please apologize As I don't know what should I tag this question, I tag it with very public tags.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of help to you? :)

As far as i know it's called magnet links... :)

[How do I make the website execute links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329757/how-do-i-make-the-website-execute-links)

Edit: Changed link to more appropriate...

Comment: At least I learned what should I call that, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yea.. sorry for the "incompleteness", but I do not have much experience using this.. :)

Comment: Your help was great. That link is what I was looking for... thanks again.